# jquery hover image keep content open until mouseout

Tags: jquery, html

How do i get this script, a click function converted to a hover function effect.

`enter code here` http://jsfiddle.net/K55ct/78/

I would like to hover the small box, and be able to mouse over the div content below for as long as I'd like, then on mouse out have the div hide again

Comment: Why do people prefer downvoting rather than answering the question.. ?

Answer (score 1):

change the html to this

```
<div id="footerSlideContainer"> 
   <div id="footerSlideButton"></div>
   <div id="footerSlideContent">
      <div id="footerSlideText">
         <div id="footer_higher">
            <div id="footer_content">
               <div class="footbox"></div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

now the Button is inside the container. Now you can use the container for the `$('#footerSlideContainer').hover()` function. This function allows two parameters, one function on the mouse in and one on the mouse out, so you jQuery part would look like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#footerSlideContainer').hover(function () {
            $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '230px' });
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');
        },
        function() {
            $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' });
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');
        }
    );      
});
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MwChT/)

**EDIT**
To keep the color change the CSS to:

```
#footerSlideContainer{position:fixed;top:50px;width:360px;left:0px}
#footerSlideButton{background:red;position:fixed;top:0;left:0px;width:50px;height:50px}
#footerSlideContainer:hover #footerSlideButton{background:green}
#footerSlideContent{height:0;background:blue}
```

Comment: thanks, in my original post i failed to mention, i wanted to keep the color on the hover state the same when i scroll over the div. The hover color is green, so how would i go about that. I know the click function you add a toggleclass.clicked

Comment: Daniel working great thanks ! I inserted a login form box http://jsfiddle.net/MwChT/80/  Do you know how to prevent the div from closing when you hover over the drop down selection box ?

Comment: Looking at this fiddle in Safari looks fine but in Firefox it is a mess.